# EntityKey.EntityKeyValues Primary value is null

Tags: entity-framework

```
 var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
    string.Join(",",objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues.Select(item=>item.Value.ToString()).ToArray());
```

this code which get primary key by ef 6.0,
but the table have three primary key,when I run this code,the value about EntityKeyValues is null,I dont't know why it is null,and I how get primary value?

Comment: why you are using objectContext and not the DbContext?

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This soultion is using MetadataWorkspace to retrieve all primary keys names from any entity. you can modify it to you wish so that fit to your soultion.

The domain entity must have a namepsace, otherwise you will get an null Reference exception!.

```
namespace EntityFrameworkDemo
{
  public class User
  {

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long SecondId { get; set; }

    public bool Checked { get; set; }

  }
}
```

---

```
public class Program
{
  public class MyDbContext : DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public MyDbContext(string connectionString)
          : base("name=" + connectionString)
    {
    }
  }
  public static IEnumerable<string> GetEntityKeys(DbContext dbContext, Type type)
  {
    var keys = new Collection<string>();

    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
    var edmMembers = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
      .GetType(type.Name, type.Namespace, DataSpace.CSpace)
      .MetadataProperties
      .Where(mp => mp.Name == "KeyMembers")
      .Select(x => x.Value)
      .Cast<ReadOnlyCollection<EdmMember>>();

    foreach (var key in edmMembers)
    {
      foreach (var edmMember in key)
      {
        keys.Add(edmMember.Name);
      }
    }

    return keys;
  }

  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyDbContext>());

    using (var myDbContext = new MyDbContext("DatabaseConnectionString1"))
    {
      myDbContext.Users.Add(new User());
      myDbContext.SaveChanges();

      var user = myDbContext.Users.First();
      var keys = GetEntityKeys(myDbContext, user.GetType());

      foreach (var key in keys)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(key);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Output:

> Id
>
> SecondId

Comment: I know why it get null,because I add a new record,I have not saved to database,so it can't get any value,thank you all the same.

Comment: @Daniel this soultion is work donot forget to mark the answer good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I know why it get null,because I add a new record,I have not saved to database,so it can't get any value,thank you all the same.

Comment: did you tried my new apporach? this will solve your problem see my answer below